# Firebase data insertion not working in onPressed function

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that writes data to a subcollection in firebase. It works as intended when I call the function in "innitState". But when I call this function in an onPressed function it does not work.

here is the code that writes data to the database. It resides in a class dedicated to performing CRUD actions:

```
  static Future<void> pushGoal(bool isLongTerm, String id) async {
    final userCollection = _db.collection('Users').doc(id);

    final goals = userCollection.collection('goals');

    await goals.add({'testing': 'testing'});
  }
```

I have wrapped this function in another function called addGoal() in my homescreen class. I understand this is not necessary, but i was just trying to get it to work. Here is the function:

```
  Future<void> addGoal() async {
    try {
      await FirestoreController.pushGoal(false, authController.getUser!.uid);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

When this function is called in innitState() the information is added. But when I try to use it in the on pressed function it does not work. Here is the onPressed function:

```
onPressed: () async {
    if (_goalFormKey.currentState!
        .validate()) {
        try {
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
               .collection('Users')
                .doc(authController
                .getUser!.uid)
                .collection('goals')
            .add({'test': 'test'});
        } catch (e) {
            print(e);
        }
    Goal goal = Goal(
    title: _goalTitle,
    );
    shapeShift();
    moveDiagonalDown();
    fadeInIcon();
}
```

why would this be happening? I am very confused as to why the information is passed to the database when it is called in the innitState() function and not when the button is pressed

Comment: Can you share code of init function , and why aren't you using pushgoal function in onpressed function

Comment: @BouncyBits I tried using pushGoal but it didnt work. I have a function in my homescreen that signs in a test user. I modeled the addGoal after that one minus the sign in methods.

The code in the innit function is very basic. its just those functions being called within the overriden innit state that is used with any other stateless widget

Comment: Can you check the value of `authController.getUser!.uid` before adding to firebase, because rest seems just fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the `set` method with merge instead of `add`. Like this:

```
.set({
   'test': 'test',
}, SetOptions(merge: true))
```